# Collect GPS Location and Compass Direction at time of camera capture?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My app currently uses the camera with a custom overlay to take and save a picture.

Ideally, I would like to collect the following 3 paramaters at the time of photo capture as well:

1. Precise GPS Location
2. Compass direction
3. Phone tilt

I'm mainly focused on getting items 1 & 2. Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: `CoreLocation` and `CoreMotion`

Comment: any guidance on how I can implement both of these after I've already called UIImagePickerController with a custom overlay?

Comment: Did you Find the Solution? Please share I am also looking for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few variables you should declare on .h file of your viewController

```
float locLat;   //for latitude
float locLon;   //for longitude
float direction;  // for angle in radian
CLLocationManager *Manager;
```

in .m file at viewdidload method

```
Manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
Manager.delegate = self; 
Manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
Manager.distanceFilter = 1.0; 
[Manager startUpdatingLocation];
[Manager startUpdatingHeading];
```

These delegate method wil be called for where you get location updates

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    userlat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    userlon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
}
```

This will give you compass values updates

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading 
{
    float direction = newHeading.trueHeading;    
}
```

You can use these three values at the imagepicker's didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate method.

Comment: How do we get 3. Title? via accelerometer?